# DependencyProperty not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a simple WPF window with a TabItem containing a ComboBox with colors and a custom Canvas drawing a rectangle with that color. In my PaintCanvas I have a DependencyProperty like this:

```
class PaintCanvas : System.Windows.Controls.Canvas
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PaintObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "PaintObject", typeof(PaintObject), typeof(PaintCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(OnPaintObjectChanged));


    public PaintObject PaintObject
    {
        get { return this.GetValue(PaintObjectProperty) as PaintObject; }
        set 
        {
            this.SetValue(PaintObjectProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnPaintObjectChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PaintCanvas canvas = (PaintCanvas)d;

        // Update stuff

        canvas.InvalidateVisual();
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);

        if (PaintObject != null)
        {
            dc.DrawRectangle(new SolidColorBrush(PaintObject.Color), null, new Rect(0, 0, PaintObject.Width, PaintObject.Height));
        }
    }
}
```

The PaintObject dependency property is bound in xaml to its corresponding property in PaintViewModel:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem DataContext="{Binding PaintViewModel}">
        <StackPanel >
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}" SelectedItem="{Binding Color}" />
            <my:PaintCanvas Width="100" Height="100" PaintObject="{Binding PaintObject}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

PaintViewModel is a property in the Window's ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel
{
    PaintViewModel paintViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        paintViewModel = new PaintViewModel();
    }

    public PaintViewModel PaintViewModel
    {
        get { return paintViewModel; }
    }

    ...
}
```

The actual PaintViewModel:

```
class PaintViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    PaintObject paintObject;
    ObservableCollection<Color> colors = new ObservableCollection<Color>();
    Color currentColor;

    public PaintObject PaintObject
    {
        get { return paintObject; }
        set { paintObject = value; RaisePropertyChanged("PaintObject"); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Color> Colors
    {
        get { return colors; }
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get { return currentColor; }
        set { 
            currentColor = value; 
            RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
            paintObject.Color = currentColor;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PaintObject");
        }
    }

    // Constructors and INotifyPropertyChanged stuff... 
}
```

The TabItem seems to be correctly bound to the view model, because the color combobox works as it should. However, although the paint object is updated and RaisePropertyChanged("PaintObject") is called, the DependencyProperty in PaintCanvas is never updated. What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: How do you know that "the DependencyProperty in PaintCanvas is never updated"? Did you set a breakpoint in `OnPaintObjectChanged` or simply because the color doesn't change?

Comment: @Clemens: Yes, both. :-)

Comment: (Is the OnPaintObjectChanged method called ?, sorry, simultaneous comments)

Comment: No, the OnPaintObjectChanged is never called, that's what puzzles me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see that you change reference to PaintObject, you cahanged one of the properties of it(Color) and fire as PaintObject is changed, and since it is not, dependency property doesnt refresh

As a solution, you can add Color dependency property in the PaintCanvas, and bind Color to PaintObject.Color in xaml

```
<my:PaintCanvas Width="100" Height="100" PaintObject="{Binding PaintObject}" Color={Binding PaintObject.Color} />
```

And if you not forget to call NotifyPropertyChanged of Color property in PaintObject, PaintConvas Color property will be fired to be changed

*I see some mess in your  design, try to keep things simple*

Comment: Right, that won't work unless the PaintObject's properties are also either dependency properties or raise a PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Thanks, That was it! Creating a new paint object instead of jsut changing the Color works fine, and I suppose that your suggestion of binding that specific property would also work. Supposing that PaintObject is a much more complex object with many properties that may change, do you have a suggestion how to make this binding?

Comment: And also, what is the mess in the design that you are referring to? I should mention that the reason for two different view models are that there are actually many TabItems that look the same. In my real application, I have a CustomControl that is bound to PaintViewModel in this way, and the PaintObject is also more complicated. But I don't mind refactoring if things can be done better.

Comment: Well, you have several options, you can create an event in PaintObject, and subscribe from dependency property change, you can bind to all properties by code, using BindingOperations, you can clone PoinObject as you did already...

Comment: @ekholm, hard to do recommendations without having hole logic in mind. I don't like that viewmodel keeps colors, because it is view stuff, is not clar if PaintObject ViewModel or Model and so on, but again it all depends from business logic you are dong, so I may be wrong

Comment: I see. I created this example to try to isolate my problem and make things clearer, so no need to worry about that. :-) But thanks again for your answer.